# UIDatePicker minimumDate and maximumDate

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm trying to set a minimum and maximum date to limit the selection of the user, but it doesn't work:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let datePickerView : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        tfDateNaissance.inputView = datePickerView

        let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
        let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

        components.year = -18
        let minDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

        components.year = -150
        let maxDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

        datePickerView.minimumDate = minDate
        datePickerView.maximumDate = maxDate


        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        let pickerToolBar = UIToolbar()
        pickerToolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black //you can change the style
        pickerToolBar.translucent = true
        pickerToolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // or other colours
        pickerToolBar.sizeToFit()

        let spaceButtonPicker = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButtonPicker = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Ok", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker:")
        pickerToolBar.setItems([cancelButtonPicker, spaceButtonPicker], animated: false)
        pickerToolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        tfDateNaissance.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar
}


    func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

        //        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        //
        //        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

        tfDateNaissance.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    }

    func cancelDatePicker(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
        if tfProjet.isFirstResponder(){
            tfProjet.resignFirstResponder()
        } else if tfDateNaissance.isFirstResponder(){
            tfDateNaissance.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```

I found this code on stack overflow, I get no errors, but I can select 2200 as year for exemple. I think it's because it's an input view, so how to to ?

Comment: Try setting the maximum and minimum before setting it as inputView

Comment: Did you check the value of `minDate` and `maxDate`? Are they the one wanted?

Comment: @larme it display : minDate NSDate 1998-02-16 14:42:31 UTC 0x7b66ba10 and maxDate NSDate 1866-02-16 15:33:10 UTC 0x7b66ba20 So it's ok

Comment: From what I can see your minimum date is later than the maximum date, haven't checked it, but I'd ignore such limits myself or show an empty picker, either way the range is dubious.

Comment: @A-Live Yes that's ok now min is max and max is min

Comment: Does it work for you now ? If so, please write a short answer to summarize the problem.

Comment: why is the `minDate` is later than the `maxDate`? the `minDate` should be the earlier date...

Answer (score 0):

The minDate was later than the maxDate:

```
    components.year = -150
    let minDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

    components.year = -18
    let maxDate: NSDate = gregorian.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

    datePickerView.minimumDate = minDate
    datePickerView.maximumDate = maxDate
```